# How to change the date format in COBOL?

Tags: date, cobol

Is there a function to change the date from MMDDYYYY to the written format(don't know what you call it)?

For example:

03052014 -> March 05, 2014

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code are you using that produces the `MMDDYYYY` format?

Comment: The date is retrieved from a text file. I just want to change it without using evaluate if possible.

Comment: What COBOL, what OS? Do you users like the day and year jumping about as the month changes? Why 05 not 5? What are you going to do if there is no function? Look at the manual for your COBOL. If it has Intrinsic Functions, those are all there are.

Comment: @Bill Woodger COBOL 85, Windows 8 Visual Cobol, This is a homework assignment and it is 05 inside the text file. I don't have a manual, just a text book that does include intrinsic functions, but I don't see what I'm looking for. Hence, why I'm asking the community if there is an easy function like makeDateLookNice(03052014).

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think you have an Intrinsic Function (part of the language) to do it.

You may be able to write a User Defined Function (you can use your favourite search engine to find out how, but ignore SQL User Defined Functions).

We don't really have "libraries" in the same way as many languages do.

As you would have to do if you make it a UDF, you'll have to code it.

The day-number, comma and year are simple re-formatting with fixed positions.

The month-name you can get by using the month number for subscripting, with a table of month-names defined in your program.

The month-names are variable in length, the rest fixed.

To put together your final result, you could `STRING month-name ( month-number ) DELIMITED BY SPACE date-fixed-data DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO date-field-for-printing`.

This will give you the jumping-about formatted date. Drives you nuts whilst trying to scan for dates on microfiche :-)

COBOL is about writing code, not finding a handy function. So for your coursework, you'll need to write code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I will just use Evaluate to determine the name of the month, and then String it together with the day and year.

Comment: Well, I see I left out the subscript from my answer. Corrected now. It's not good to scatter literals throughout your PROCEDURE DIVISION. They have a habit of increasing maintenance - you use the same literal twice in a program, then they both need to change, but the maintainer only hits one. Month-names aren't going to change, you say? Until your program is implemented for another language (Portuguese, whatever...) when suddenly it starts outputting a mixture of Maio and May. Depends how your marker feels about things I suppose, not me :-)